# Possible to get a list of scheduleditems?

Tags: development, event-receivers, schedule

Is it possible to get a list of ScheduledItems from SharePoint in C# (event receiver)?

For example, I've created a ScheduledItem and called the .Schedule() method. I'd expect this ScheduledItem to appear in the list (however I go about retrieving this 'list').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes you can, Since its scheduleitems i guess these items are in a
>   list. so all you need to do is go through each listitem and check
>   item's approval status, if its = "Scheduled" if it is then you can add
>   it to a custom list or however you want it :)

Hope it helped ;)

Comment: The problem is that the item in question isn't appearing as scheduled. Basically, my problem is that I'm creating a scheduled item on an event receiver, but when I call .Schedule() it's obviously calling the event receiver again, so I  need a way of telling it not run the ScheduledItem creation code again (i.e. check if it's already scheduled). Approval status is still appearing as 'Draft' by the time it gets back to the code. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: can you add code your using please so that i have a look !